# Error while using Spring STS Starter Wizard

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I create a lot of Spring boot apps and I like to use Spring STS starter wizard to get me going, but all of a sudden today I started seeing an error window popup every time I try to open the "Spring Starter Wizard".

STS version: 3.7.2

Here is the error in the popup window.
[image]

Here is the error that I see in the logs.

```
java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://start.spring.io
12129         at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizard.init(NewSpringBootWizard.java:75)
12130         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:119)
12131         at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
12132         at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
12133         at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
12134         at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
12135         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
12136         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
12137         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
12138         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
12139         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
12140         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
12141         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
12142         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
12143         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
12144         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
12145         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
12146         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
12147         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
12148         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
12149         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
12150         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
12151         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
12152         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
12153         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
12154         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
12155         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
12156         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
12157         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12158         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
12159         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12160         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
12161         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
12162         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
12163         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

I tried accessing http://start.spring.io/sts through my browser and I get this message.

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('start.spring.io') does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has resolved now. It seems there was some issue with http://start.spring.io/sts. It is back up now.

Comment: Indeed, there was an outage yesterday, sorry about that. STS 3.7 doesn't use `/sts` by the way. Only the first version supporting that wizard does.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the network setting in the **STS**.

> Select Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection and
>   change the setting.

Set Active Provider to manual then edit the host and port details in proxy entries. Apply the setting and click ok.

This worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Thank You